Type of values of createDirectLine parameters
I couldn't find, in the repository files, a place that specifies the type of value for the parameters of createDirectLine. Can someone help me with this?
I found only the type of fields domain, conversationId e webSocket

Sorry, your question seems a little ambiguous to me. Regarding the parameter(s) 'types of values', it reads like you want to know the actual type, which can be viewed here. But I think you are actually wanting examples that demonstrate the kind of value that is acceptable for each parameter. Can you clarify for me?

I found the props types here thanks to Steve Kanberg's comment
The types of properties follow:
export interface DirectLineOptions {
    secret?: string,
    token?: string,
    conversationId?: string,
    watermark?: string,
    domain?: string,
    webSocket?: boolean,
    pollingInterval?: number,
    streamUrl?: string,
    timeout?: number,
    botAgent?: string,
    conversationStartProperties?: any
} 

